# Send input to Google colab using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run the below code in Google colab.

```
# code for load the file
number = input('Enter the number')
print('You entered',number)
```

I saved this code in a file and load it by selenium and when i ran the code it showing the input box but i don't know how to send the number using selenium and python. Advance Thanks for the Help

P.S If you want any clarification feel free to ask

Comment: can you post the soup file?

Comment: @Darkknight i don't understand